# What can I take as a gift from Poland for my host, which is small and light?

Tags: couchsurfing, gifts, souvenirs

I'm from Poland and I'd like to try some CouchSurfing after the trip in the mountains. I'd have to carry all things on my back, so this should be small and very light. A normally proposed souvenir from Poland is polish vodka Żubrówka, but it's not an option to carry it in the mountains for over the week.

So, what can be taken, that would make the host happy and don't make my back hurt?

The most appreciated answers will be those based on your experience and/or expert knowledge of CouchSurfing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to travel a lot I would say that you can also take:

1. some handmade laces from Koniakow, what is a world known place with the tradition of over 200 years of lace making
2. handmade christmas or eastern decorations made of straw - very light :D
3. another option for you would be some amber.

All thoses products you can find in "CEPELIA" in the shops spread all over Poland that are promoting local decorative handicraft and design.

Comment: Amber, every time. The Poles do gorgeous hand-made silver jewellery with inset amber, is popular wherever you go. Once I also got a tiny model sailing ship made of amber and wood, which is exquisite.

Answer (score 6):

If you want something different, Polish and light, it would be worth having a look at [Polish](http://leotravel.pl/discover-poland/culture-folk-arts-and-crafts-en.php) [paper](http://www.polskiinternet.com/english/info/artpaper.html) [cutting](http://www.polartcenter.com/Wycinanki_Paper_Cuts_s/169.htm).  A bunch of those will not weigh much and should definitely be a souvenir uniquely from Poland.